# React/Typescript: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'object'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I import data from a different file but in `render()` I can't seem to get the properties e.g `id` of the entities in json `data`. On debug, I can actually see the `id` e.g 233765 when I hover the mouse over it but typescript for some reason gives the error here below the code. Where's the fault in my definitions?

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import * as data from '../../team.json';

interface Props {
  //props
}

interface State {
   nextRacers: Array<object>;
   jockeys: Array<object>;
}

export class Race extends React.Component<Props, State> {

  constructor(props: Props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          jockeys: data as object as <ArrayObject>, 
          nextRacers: [],
      };
  }

  render() {
      const r = this.state.jockeys;
      const x = r.map((value, i) => {
          console.log(value.id);
      });
      console.log(x);
  }
      
}
```

I get an error;

> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'object'.

I've googled quite extensively with many results poppin but cant seem to apply the logic to this simple thing I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript is inferring that `value` is of type `object` which has no property `id`. The way that the jockeys are being casted (`as object as`) also doesn't seem right. You should create a `Jockey` interface to represent the jockey data structure and use that type definition instead of `object`.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as data from '../../team.json';

interface Jockey {
    id: string;
}

interface Props {
    //props
}

interface State {
    nextRacers: any[];
    jockeys: Jockey[];
}

export class Race extends React.Component<Props, State> {

    state: State;

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            jockeys: data as Jockey[],
            nextRacers: []
        };
    }

    render() {
        const r = this.state.jockeys;
        const x = r.map((value: Jockey, i: number) => {
            console.log(value.id);
        });
        console.log(x);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. With `jockeys:data as Jockey[]` I get >>>Type 'typeof "*.json"' cannot be converted to type 'Jockey[]'.
  Property 'includes' is missing in type 'typeof "*.json"'. However when I change it to `jockeys: data as object as Jockey[]` it works. What's the logic? Should I leave it as the latter without runnung into issues later on?

Comment: You can try importing the data via the `require` instead of using `import` since it is not really a module. `var jockies:Jockey[] = require('../../team.json');`

Answer (score 1):

> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'object'.

You have `jockeys: Array<object>;` Change to `jockeys: Array<{id: any}>;` or a similarly appropriate annotation.

Comment: And how do I change the state in the constructor? I get > Type '{ jockeys: object[]; nextRacers: never[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<State>'.
  Types of property 'jockeys' are incompatible.
    Type 'object[]' is not assignable to type '{ id: any; }[]'.
      Type 'object' is not assignable to type '{ id: any; }'.
        Property 'id' is missing in type '{}'.